# PHP vs JavaScript Regex

Tags: php, javascript, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to match this regex

```
/((TOSS-UP|BONUS)\n+([^\n]+)\n+ANSWER:([^\n]+))/
```

to this data

```
TOSS-UP
? ipsum dolor sit amet
ANSWER: lorem
BONUS
when in the course of ? events
ANSWER: human
```

.

I use stuff like RegexPal to make regexes, so I tested it first in JavaScript with

```
({regex}).exec({data});
```

which returns, as expected,

```
[
"TOSS-UP\n? ipsum dolor sit amet\nANSWER: lorem",
"TOSS-UP\n? ipsum dolor sit amet\nANSWER: lorem",
"TOSS-UP",
"? ipsum dolor sit amet",
" lorem"
]
```

.

But then in PHP, testing with

```
preg_match_all("{regex}","{data}",$arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

returns no matches and an empty array.

It's probably some difference between PHP-style regex and JS regex (unless I'm doing something really stupid, which I've been known for). Since I only know JS-style regex, I'm not sure what to do.

I tried to look it up, but official documentation is horrendously complicated and unhelpful, and the comparison at http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html doesn't list any differences that matter.

Hence, here I am.

Comment: Include your exact PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I was being stupid after all.

My PHP code was

```
preg_match_all("{regex}","TOSS-UP
? ipsum dolor sit amet
ANSWER: lorem
BONUS
when in the course of ? events
ANSWER: human",$arr);
```

And the string in the middle apparently evaluates to something like

```
"TOSS-UP ? ipsum dolor sit amet ANSWER: lorem BONUS when in the course of ? events ANSWER: human"
```

Which has no line breaks, and the regex doesn't match. Facepalm.

I guess I never noticed it before since I was doing the multiline quotes with HTML code, which really isn't sensitive to line breaks.

Let this be a warning to all! :D